"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" Electron


Resource of CalHeatmap not found when testing app in Electron. I check on my vscode that clicked new CalHeatmap(); will jump into the source file, so it should be work, but when try to npm start the resource not found.
I tried change to be more relative path like this
import CalHeatmap from './node_modules/cal-heatmap/src/index.d.ts';
import './node_modules/cal-heatmap/dist/cal-heatmap.css';

But it got error Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Notes:

In load.js focus on imports and focus on line <script type="module" src="./load.js"></script> in index.html. Let me know if you still need info.
I already manage to get work of cal-heatmap in VITE then I try to make into Electron. In VITE project all it's fine, but in Electron project it's not.
If you need more information, let me know in the comment.

load.js
import CalHeatmap from './node_modules/cal-heatmap';
import './node_modules/cal-heatmap/cal-heatmap.css';

// Instantiate CalHeatmap
const cal = new CalHeatmap();

const _data = {
    data: {
        source: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/main/docs/data/seattle-weather.csv',
        type: 'csv',
        x: 'date',
        y: d => +d['temp_max'],
        groupY: 'max',
    },
    date: { start: new Date('2012-01-01') },
    range: 12,
    scale: {
        color: {
            type: 'threshold',
            range: ['#14432a', '#166b34', '#37a446', '#4dd05a'],
            domain: [10, 20, 30],
        },
    },
    domain: {
        type: 'month',
        gutter: 4,
        label: { text: 'MMM', textAlign: 'start', position: 'top' },
    },
    subDomain: { type: 'ghDay', radius: 2, width: 11, height: 11, gutter: 4 },
}


cal.paint(_data);

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
        Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
        and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
    </p>
    <div id="cal-heatmap"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./load.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


How are you creating the window? By default, node modules aren't exposed to the renderer (the front-end). You may want to use a preload script, or use webPreferences.nodeIntegration (but beware of security considerations!).

@OskarGrosser I use default tutorial for the creating window. I already tried for preload script but produce error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module and other error like module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. Currently, I develop my app for personal use, so low security is not priority. I will be looking for webPreferences.nodeIntegration more.

@Restu Please, do never ever consider webPreferences.nodeIntegration unless you absolutely need to, and never enable it because you got an error. For your error: Don't use import in your preload script. When following the standard tutorial, you must use require inside your preload script, as in the example linked to by @Oskar Grosser. Since this is the next step in the tutorial, I suggest you follow the tutorial until the end before experimenting so you have a better idea of what to do where.

@TheKvist cal-heatmap is module type, so it's not working using require. I'm about giving up learning electron. The tutorial is fine. But they make a simple like import to be difficult to implement that because they make it to be isolated outside module. I know it was for security, but the tutorial for loading module ES, tbh, hard to figure out.
